# Use Quantization on HuggingFace Transformers models

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, quantization

I'm learning **Quantization**, and am experimenting with **Section 1** of this [notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/quantization/notebooks/bert/Bert-GLUE_OnnxRuntime_quantization.ipynb).

I want to use this code on my own models.

Hypothetically, I only need to assign to `model` variable in **Section 1.2**

---

```py
# load model
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(configs.output_dir)
model.to(configs.device)
```

My models are from a different library: `from transformers import pipeline`. So `.to()` throws an `AttributeError`.

My Model:

```
pip install transformers
```

```py
from transformers import pipeline

unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model='bert-base-uncased')
model = unmasker("Hello I'm a [MASK] model.")
```

Output:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased were not used when initializing BertForMaskedLM: ['cls.seq_relationship.bias', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForMaskedLM from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForMaskedLM from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
```

---

**How might I run the linked Quantization code on my example model?**

Please let me know if there's anything else I should clarify in this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pipeline` approach won't work for Quantisation as we need the models to be returned. You can however, use `pipeline` for testing the original [models](https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=fill-mask&language=en&library=pytorch&dataset=dataset:bookcorpus&sort=downloads) for timing etc.

---

**Quantisation Code:**

`token_logits` contains the tensors of the quantised model.

You could place a `for-loop` around this code, and replace `model_name` with `string` from a `list`.

```py
model_name = bert-base-uncased
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name )
model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
    
sequence = "Distilled models are smaller than the models they mimic. Using them instead of the large " \
f"versions would help {tokenizer.mask_token} our carbon footprint."

inputs = tokenizer(sequence, return_tensors="pt")
mask_token_index = torch.where(inputs["input_ids"] == tokenizer.mask_token_id)[1]
    
token_logits = model(**inputs).logits

# <- can stop here
```

[Source](https://huggingface.co/models?sort=downloads)